# How to override a global variable inside a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


root = Tk()

p = None

def set_text(text):
    global p

    filePath.delete(0,END)
    filePath.insert(0,text)

    p = filePath.get()

    return


def get_path():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    json1_file = open(filename)
    return filename

root['bg'] = '#fafafa'

root.title('json parser')

root.geometry('500x300')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame_top = Frame(root, bg='#ffb700', bd=5)

frame_top.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.25)

frame_bottom = Frame(root, bg='#ffb700', bd=5)
frame_bottom.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.1)


filePath= Entry(frame_top, bg='white', font=30)
filePath.pack(side=LEFT)

b1 = Button(frame_top,text="choose file",command=lambda:set_text(get_path()))
b1.pack(side=RIGHT)
print(p)

info = Label(frame_bottom, text='programm', bg='#ffb700', font=40)
info.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am new to programming and this is my first experience with tkinter.
I need the result of the `filePath.get()` function to use it outside the function. I tried assigning it to `p` variable as a global variable but it didn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is `cityField`?

Comment: my mistake, corrected. I'm sorry

Comment: Why do you think that `p` is not updated? Did you try to print out the value of p after `p = filePath.get()` inside `set_text()`?

Comment: yes, the result is not printed

Comment: @dev_beginer you are printing `p` after you assign `b1` a value. It will be None, because `print` is executed immediately after `b1=...`. The value of `p` changes when you actually press the button. Try printing it inside the `set_text()` as @acw1668 pointed out.

Comment: yes, but I need to use the filePath.get () value outside of the function

Comment: So, .....use it!

Comment: @dev_beginer you should be able to do that. Try creating another button and print `p` when you click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wrong with p variable assigning.P already has value.But  you must attention to mainloop() mechanism . In the beginning when program run p has not value.after pressing  b1 button p take value but print(p) don't call again because mainloop() just refresh widget no entire of code.